# Your recent app update has been rejected for not adhering to the Google Play Developer Program Policies

Tags: android, policy

I received this message from Google:

> We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.
>
> We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.
>
> You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

As I understand my app is not collecting or sharing any kind of data.
I am using below libraries in my app if any one of them is collecting or sharing data (my app is accessing user's contact list with photos )

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0` collects user data and since is part of your app you have to declare it.

More here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469 :

"In addition to reviewing how your app collects and shares user data, you should also review how any third-party code (such as third-party libraries or SDKs) in your app collects and shares such data. It's your responsibility to ensure that any such code used in your app is compliant with Play Developer Program policies. You must reflect data collection or sharing carried out by such third-party code in the Data safety form for your app."